# Eu 261 query on multi flight ticket during BA pilots strike

Tags: international-travel, eu, cancellations, compensation, british-airways

We purchased a multi flight BA ticket, Manchester to Heathrow, Heathrow to Seattle for 20 Aug 2019 flying back from Los Angeles to Heathrow then connection to Manchester departing LA on 9 September.
We were notified by BA on 23 August that the return flights were cancelled. BA flew us back 2 days late on 11 September and have paid our hotel costs for the two days delay but have declined to pay EU261 compensation claiming we had 14 days notice.
My contention is that all the flights were on the same ticket and the journey had commenced before the return flights were cancelled therefore removing our option to cancel the trip.
Do I have a justified claim and if so can I claim for both legs of the return journey or just one?

Comment: On mobile at the moment so can’t cite, hence comment, but EU261 is per journey so you did have 14 days notice for the disruption to the return journey, and the compensation is based on the delay at the final destination in the journey, not each leg.

Comment: Related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/133139/flight-re-scheduled-two-weeks-before-planned-departure